Upgrade quasar - ReferenceError: process is not defined
I have a old project and I try to update this (quasar 1 to 2)
here the version I use:


vue@3.5.4
quasar@2.16.11
node v22.7.0


at this point I have an error in my console from my browser:
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at eval (index.js:7:1)
    at ./src/router/index.js (app.js:282:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1487:32)
    at fn (app.js:1785:21)
    at eval (app.js:23:79)
    at ./.quasar/app.js (app.js:19:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1487:32)
    at fn (app.js:1785:21)
    at eval (client-entry.js:239:67)
    at ./.quasar/client-entry.js (app.js:30:1)

I tried to understand what Is missing but I'm a little lost
I post also the actual package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "@quasar/app-webpack": "^3.13.4",
    "@quasar/babel-preset-app": "^2.0.3",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.12",
    "@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar": "^4.0.0-beta.16",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.5.4",
    "@vuex-orm/core": "^0.36.4",
    "apexcharts": "^3.53.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "encoding-japanese": "^2.2.0",
    "js-md5": "^0.8.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "quasar": "^2.16.11",
    "stylus-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.5.4",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.6.2",
    "vue-avatar": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-i18n": "^10.0.0",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.25.1",
    "@eslint/compat": "^1.1.1",
    "@eslint/js": "^9.10.0",
    "@quasar/icongenie": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^5.0.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^8.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.30.0",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "quasar-app-extension-ide-helper": "1.0.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 22.7.0",
    "npm": ">= 10.8.2",
    "yarn": ">= 1.22.22"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version, not dead, ie >= 11"
  ]

I have another error in the console maybe I don't know if this have side effects or not but:
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount app: mount target selector "#app" returned null.

Sorry if the information is confuse, I'm also confuse where I need to check

process is a global variable that only exists within Node -- in your browser, it will not exist, hence the error. It's hard to give a solution given the lack of code, but it's likely the old version of quasar was defining process, or variables within process, and that's no longer occurring. Often, the standard is for build tools to replace something like process.env.MY_VARIABLE with "foo" for the browser, but if that's failing to happen, you can run into the above error. Are you using something like that (process.env.MY_VARIABLE) in your app?

hum ok, I start to understand, maybe! There a multiple of call of process to check the env like this process.env.STAGING === true

yeah, I never had much luck upgrading vue2 -> vue3 without also switching to vitejs

I use quasar-cli, so seems to be suffisant for my project: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env

That's likely the issue then, that process.env.STAGING isn't getting replaced with true/false any more in the browser. You'll want to following these instructions to add STAGING: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env#adding-to-process-env
